# LineString Adding and Removing

Tags: openlayers, linestring

Following the example [Draw Feature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html)

in `openlayers 4` i was able to `addInteraction` and successfully drew a line.

My questions here are

1. How do i capture all the lines drawn and populate them on the map again?
2. How do i remove the latest drawn line. (Something like an undo button that keeps removing the latest line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can define a drawend function and grab your drawn geometry.

   ```
               currentProcess = new ol.interaction.Draw($.extend({
                   source: self.VectorSource,
                   type: 'LineString'
               }, options));
               self.Map.olMap.addInteraction(currentProcess);
               currentProcess.on('drawend', function (e) {
                   console.log("drawend");
                   var format = new ol.format.WKT();
                                               e.feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:32636');
                                               var wkt = format.writeFeature(e.feature);
                                               data.Geom = wkt;
                   self.Map.olMap.removeInteraction(currentProcess);
               });
   ```

Here is the WKT your geometry data and then with this code you can add feature to layer.

```
vectorSource.addFeature(geometryData);
```

2. You can easily remove your added geometry data from map with removeFeature function.

   featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);

Sources:

[addFeature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeature)

[removeFeature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#removeFeature)